# Material button renders icon as a white block

Tags: android, material-design

I am trying to create a sign in with google button with material theme, but the icon is shown as a white block. I am using sign in assets provided by google [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/images/signin-assets.zip).

If I use material button with material theme

**Button XML**

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
       android:id="@+id/btn_material"
       style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Sign In with Google"
       app:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
       ...
</style>
```

[image]

But if I use a appcompat theme with a normal button it works fine

**Button XML**

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/btn_appcompat"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:drawableStart="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
     android:text="Sign In with Google"
/>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
         ...
</style>
```

[image]

So how could I make button icon to appear properly in material theme?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, the `app:icon` is tinted with the `app:iconTint` color as per the [MaterialButton documentation](https://material.io/develop/android/components/material-button/)

You can disable this behavior by adding `app:iconTint="@null"` to your button:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
   android:id="@+id/btn_material"
   style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.Icon"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="Sign In with Google"
   app:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
   app:iconTint="@null" />
```

Comment: I forgot about tint .. thanks a lot